# Oracle's Java 1.8 appears to not actually install itself

Tags: macos, install, java

I have searched for answers this problem, but nobody seems to have such a basic problem as I have. I have Java 1.7 installed and tried to install 1.8 - both through the Java control panel and manually downloading 1.8 (45) and running that. Each installation method appears to work without issue, however, Java 1.8 is not to be found on my Mac.

I have looked in the following locations:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

I even resorted to a comprehensive search after Spotlight failed to find it:

```
% sudo find / -type d -name jdk1.\*.jdk
```

That find(1) found the 1.7 installation, but not the 1.8.

So, I am puzzled, both why 1.8 did not install properly and where is it? I can mangle the links to install it manually, if somebody can point me to where I might find it, or even what I could have possible done wrong while "clicking OK" during the install.

Output from `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
     1.7.0_51, x86_64:  "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
     1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:  "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
     1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386:    "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

This is the log from an attempted install:

```
May 20 22:28:47 Jims-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[749]: PackageKit: -----             Begin install -----
May 20 22:28:52 Jims-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[749]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “JDK 8 Update 45.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7f9745c0c6d0      {NSFilePath=./postinstall,  NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/JDK%208%20Update%2045/JDK%208%20Update%2045.pkg#javaappletplugin.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.oracle.jre, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “JDK 8 Update 45.pkg”.} {
    NSFilePath = "./postinstall";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cJDK 8 Update 45.pkg\U201d.";
    NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/JDK%208%20Update%2045/JDK%208%20Update%2045.pkg#javaappletplugin.pkg";
    PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.oracle.jre";
}
May 20 22:28:53 Jims-MacBook-Pro-2.local Installer[9364]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
May 20 22:28:53 Jims-MacBook-Pro-2.local Installer[9364]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
May 20 22:28:53 Jims-MacBook-Pro-2.local Installer[9364]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

Comment: Try `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` in a Terminal and tell us what it gives you back.

Comment: % /usr/libexec/java_home -V
    Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
        1.7.0_51, x86_64: "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
        1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
        1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: The update tab of the Java control panel insists that Java 8 Update 45 is installed.

Comment: Added the java_home output to your question. Hope you don't mind. Was it the developer kit (JDK) or just the runtime (JRE) you were installing?

Comment: Especially note that Oracle's JRE is not what everyone else called a JRE it is now just the web plugin

Comment: I'm trying to install the JDK

Answer (score 1):

Run the installer again, but open the Installer Log window by choosing "Installer Log" from the Window menu or hitting <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This might help you discover if the installer is having a problem when it is trying to install Java 1.8 on your system. By default it is set to "Show Errors Only" but you can see more detail by changing it to "Show All Logs" from the drop-down in the top-left corner of the Log window.

[image: Example of Installer Log window]

Another way to see exactly what is happening when you are installing Java 1.8 is to use the following command in a Terminal window, replacing PATHTOINSTALLPACKAGE with the location of the "JDK 8 Update 45.pkg" file. The easy way to do this is to type (or copy and paste) the first part of the command up to "-pkg " and then drag and drop the PKG file (the one with the yellow cube emerging form the brown box icon) onto the Terminal window.

```
 sudo installer -verboseR -target / -pkg PATHTOINSTALLPACKAGE
```

So you should end up with something like this.

```
 sudo installer -verboseR -target / -pkg /Volumes/JDK\ 8\ Update\ 45/JDK\ 8\ Update\ 45.pkg
```

Then hit ENTER and enter your password.

You should get output that tells you exactly what is happening.

```
installer:PHASE:Preparing for installation…
installer:PHASE:Preparing the disk…
installer:PHASE:Preparing JDK 8 Update 45…
installer:PHASE:Waiting for other installations to complete…
installer:PHASE:Configuring the installation…
installer:STATUS:
installer:%5.810995
installer:PHASE:Writing files…
installer:%7.044070
installer:PHASE:Writing files…
...
...
...
installer:%79.565404
installer:PHASE:Moving items into place…
installer:%80.175556
installer:PHASE:Moving items into place…
...
...
...
installer:PHASE:Running package scripts…
installer:PHASE:Running package scripts…
...
...
...
installer:PHASE:Validating packages…
installer:%97.750000
installer:STATUS:Running installer actions…
installer:STATUS:
installer:PHASE:Finishing the Installation…
installer:STATUS:
installer:%100.000000
installer:PHASE:The software was successfully installed.
installer: The upgrade was successful.
```

If it is failing at some point it should tell you. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: thanks for the process, here is the result, I removed a lot of the intermediate text and statuses so it would fit as a comment, bottom line is it seems to have worked correctly

    installer: Package name is Java 8 Update 45
    installer: Upgrading at base path /
    installer:PHASE:Preparing for installation…
    ...
    installer:PHASE:Validating packages…
    installer:STATUS:Running installer actions…
    installer:PHASE:Finishing the Installation…
    installer:%100.000000
    installer:PHASE:The software was successfully installed.
    installer: The upgrade was successful.

Comment: So if you open the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ folder on your Mac you only have jdk1.7.0_51.jdk in there? I just downloaded and installed Java 1.8 yesterday and installed it with all the defaults and it deposited it within that folder.

Comment: Alistair - Java 1.8 does not appear anywhere. Now, after repeated attempts to install it, the Java 1.8 installer is failing.  Is there any I can back out all the versions of Java and start over from scratch?  Is there anyway to  install Java 1.8 manually?

Comment: Here is the log from the installer:

Comment: Paste the log from the install into a http://gist.github.com and paste the link here in a comment or update your question.

Comment: Alistair - I have updated my question with the entire log

Comment: Alistair - I just got back to this (after more than a year). I ended up trashing the Mac to the point I had to do a complete restore from Time Machine. So I basically started from scratch and 1.8 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jre-8unnn-macosx-x64.dmg you need to install jdk-8unnn-macosx-x64.dmg.

This is the reason why you only got the /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

Comment: I'm not convinced the OP had the same issue as you: part of their install/update log reads "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “JDK 8 Update 45.pkg”.

Comment: But the last bit ofg the log says javaappletplugin.pkg

Comment: Both JRE and JDK will install the JavaAppletPlugin.pkg -- PackageKit: packages=("PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/JDK 8 Update 121/JDK 8 Update 121.pkg#jdk180121.pkg>", "PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/JDK 8 Update 121/JDK 8 Update 121.pkg#javaappletplugin.pkg>")